# Как можно получить данные из csv файла в Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular

Вот мой запрос,ответом будет error

```
public getCompaniesBySuggestions(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get<any>(`./assets/suggestions.csv`);
}
```

Comment: Хорошо бы узнать, какой error будет.

Comment: @overthesanity спасибо за ответ помогло

Comment: Jora, если ответ помог решению задачи, СПАСИБО, конечно хорошо, но лучше, если принять ответ... Это серая галочка с лева от ответа, нажми и станет зеленой...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оформлю тогда как ответ :) Angular всегда по дефолту делает `JSON.parse(body)`, в случае с `.csv` ежу понятно, что `JSON.parse` кидает эксепшн. Вам нужно указать тип ответа (`ResponseContentType`), если хотите получить просто строку, то `{ responseType: 'text' }`, если бинарник, то `{ responseType: 'buffer' }`.